# Calculating the gap between pairs of twin primes in python

Tags: python

So I am making a program that generates a list of prime numbers and then sorts them into twin prime pairs, then calculates out what two sets of twin primes have the largest difference. I have gotten to sorting it into a list of twin prime pairs with my code, but now I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the next part happen. I am not quite sure how I can calculate the largest gap between the primes. Here is what I got so far:

```
def is_factor(n,f):
    '''
    Returns True if f is a factor of n,
OTW returns False.
Both n and f are ints.
'''
    TV = (n % f == 0)
    return TV

def properFactorsOf(n):
'''
Returns a list of the proper factors
of n.  n is an int.
f is a proper factor of n if:
    f is a factor of n
    f > 1 and f < n.
'''
    L = []
    upper = n//2 # largest f to test
    for f in range(2,upper + 1):
        if is_factor(n,f):
            L.append(f)
    return L

def is_prime(n):
'''
Returns True if n is a prime,
OTW returns False.
n is an int.
Use properFactorsOf(n) to check whether n is prime.
'''
    TV = len(properFactorsOf(n)) == 0
    return TV

def LofPrimes(n):    
'''
Returns a list of the first n primes.
Uses is_prime(n).
'''
    primes = [2,3]
    p = 5
    while len(primes) < n:
        if is_prime(p):
        primes.append(p)
        p += 2
    return primes

def twins():
    n = eval(input("How many primes?"))

    L = (LofPrimes(n)) #Makes a list consisting of the function LofPrimes(n)
    m = 1 #If m is zero it would take the zeroth position
    L3 = [] # This is the list of twins
    for i in range(len(L)-1): #keeps it in range

        tp = L[m]-L[m-1] #subtract pos 1 from pos zero
        if tp == 2: # If the difference of the pair is 2
            L3.append(([L[m-1],L[m]])) #add the twins to the list L3

        m += 1 # set m back to 1 at the end of the loop


    print(L3)
```

So I feel like I am kind of on the right path, I made some pseudo code to give you an idea on where my thought is going:
        assign a temp variable to m-1 on the first run,
        assign a temp variable to m on the second run,
        make a loop to go through the list of twins
        take the difference of m-1 from the first set and m from the second set
        in this loop calculate the max gap
        return the greatest difference

Comment: Fix the indentation of your functions.

Comment: I did. How does it look now?

Comment: I'm missing something. Twin primes *are defined* to be pairs of primes that differ by exactly two, like 41 and 43. So shouldn't your program just return 2? Are you instead talking about the distance between *pairs*, like the lower number of the upper pair minus the higher number of the lower pair? In that case, the pairs need to be consecutive. If it's calculated between all possible pairs, the 'largest gap' will always be the second-largest overall prime minus the second-smallest overall prime.

Comment: Yea, sorry I guess I should have cleared that up, let me go edit that. 

I'm confused. If it is the second largest and the second smallest numbers that give me the greatest gap, how would you had say a list of the twin primes (up to 1 mil) it would be the second to highest prime number minus 5 (because 5 is the second smallest prime)?

Comment: Suppose the list is `[(3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19)]` If we test every pair against every other pair, the biggest gap will be from 17 - 5. Instead the calculation has to happen for consecutive pair: (5, 7) minus (3,5), then (11,13) minus (5,7). and so one. This is what all of the log(n) average gap stuff is about.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still confused. How would you take 17-5? when 5 is two gaps away from 17? we know the gap between the first two twins is 0 because 5=5, and then 11-7= 4 and then 17-13=4 .... I don't understand why would you subtract 5 from 17?

Comment: I'm saying that *if* you compare **all** pairs, then you would compare `(3,5)` with every other pair, by definition. One of those other pairs will involve the second-largest prime, and that will lead to the biggest difference from 5, by definition. If you did that, it would probably not be computing what you want. Instead you want to only look at *consecutive* pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a list of the pairs of primes, what you call `L3` which could be like this:

```
L3 = [(3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43), (59, 61), 
      (71, 73), (101, 103), (107, 109), (137, 139)]
```

Then what we want to do is take the first element of a pair minus the last element of the previous pair.

We also want to accumulate a list of these values so later we can see at which index the maximum happens. The `reduce` function is good for this.

```
def helper_to_subtract_pairs(acc, x):
    return acc[:-1] + [x[0] - acc[-1]] + [x[1]]
```

Then printing

```
reduce(helper_to_subtract_pairs, L3, [0])
```

gives

```
[3, 0, 4, 4, 10, 10, 16, 10, 28, 4, 28, 139]
```

The first element happens because inside the call to `reduce` we use a starting value of `[0]` (so the first prime 3 leads to 3 - 0). We can ignore that. The final item, `139`, represents the number that would be part of the subtraction if there was one more pair on the end. But since there is not, we can ignore that too:

```
In [336]: reduce(helper_to_subtract_pairs, L3, [0])[1:-1]
Out[336]: [0, 4, 4, 10, 10, 16, 10, 28, 4, 28]
```

Now, we want the index(es) where the max occurs. For this let's use the Python recipe for `argmax`:

```
def argmax(some_list):
    return max(enumerate(some_list), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

Then we get:

```
In [338]: argmax(reduce(helper_to_subtract_pairs, L3, [0])[1:-1])
Out[338]: 7
```

telling us that the gap at index 7 is the biggest (or at least tied for the biggest). The 7th gap in this example was between (101, 103) and (71, 73) (remember Python is 0-based, so the 7th gap is really between pair 7 and pair 8).

So as a function of just the list `L3`, we can write:

```
def max_gap(prime_list):
    gaps = reduce(helper_to_subtract_pairs, prime_list, [0])[1:-1]
    max_idx = argmax(gaps)
    return gaps[max_idx], prime_list[max_idx:max_idx + 2]
```

The whole thing could look like:

```
def argmax(some_list):
    return max(enumerate(some_list), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]

def helper_to_subtract_pairs(acc, x):
    return acc[:-1] + [x[0] - acc[-1]] + [x[1]]

def max_gap(prime_list):
    gaps = reduce(helper_to_subtract_pairs, prime_list, [0])[1:-1]
    max_idx = argmax(gaps)
    return gaps[max_idx], prime_list[max_idx:max_idx + 2]    

L3 = [(3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43), (59, 61), 
      (71, 73), (101, 103), (107, 109), (137, 139)]

print max_gap(L3)
```

which prints

```
In [342]: print max_gap(L3)
(28, [(71, 73), (101, 103)])
```

It's going to be more effort to modify `argmax` to return all occurrences of the max. If this is for investigating the asymptotic growth of the gap size, you won't need to, since any max will do to summarize a particular collection of primes.

Comment: I think I understand what you are talking about now that i see the code. So when you have a small list like this one, I imagine it running through pretty quickly, but lets say that we generate a list of the first 1 million prime numbers and it splits into the 500k twins right, so It is going to take much longer to run through all 499 gaps and sort the largest right?

Comment: The part that will take a long time is locating the twin primes out of your list of all primes. Once you have the gaps, the code for choosing the max gap is efficient. But this inefficiency is a complexity fact about finding prime numbers; not something you can avoid.